# Die Bedeutung von »so« in diesem Zusammenhang

Tags: meaning

> Möchten Sie das Griffmuster eines bestimmen Akkordes herausfinden, **so** können Sie mit Hilfe der Akkordsuchmaschine den gesuchten Akkord über ein Auswahlmenü auswählen.

Hat es dieselbe Bedeutung wie **also**?

Comment: No, it means "you may" or "you can".
a few examples: http://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/search?source=auto&query=%2C+so+k%F6nnen+

Comment: Danke für den Linguee-Link!

Comment: I would say this "so" has the same meaning as "dann".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nein, das "so" dient hier nur der Markierung des Hauptsatzes, wenn ein konjunktionsloser Nebensatz vorausgeht.

Die vollständige Konstruktion ist eigentlich "Wenn [Nebensatz], so [Hauptsatz]". (Statt "so" ist auch "dann" möglich.) Das "wenn" kann entfallen (wobei der Nebensatz dann in Verberststellung rückt). Das "so" kann ebenfalls entfallen.

Wenn aber beide Partikeln entfallen, ist das Satzgefüge nicht mehr so leicht zu deuten, weil zwei Verberstsätze direkt aufeinander folgen. Daher ist bei Nebensatz ohne "wenn" das "so" viel häufiger als bei Nebensatz mit "wenn".

Answer (score -5):

***Nein***, *so* beschreibt hier, **wie** man den Akkord auswählt.

*Also* ist mehr in dem Sinne von *folglich* oder  *deshalb*:

*Wir kennen das Griffmuster des  Akkords, also können wir ihn spielen.*

Es beschreibt nicht das *wie*.