# Conditional clauses without conjunctions

Tags: usage, word-order, conjunction, subordinate-clause

I’ve come across this quotation from [Kafka’s *Tagebücher*](http://gutenberg.spiegel.de/buch/tagebucher-1910-1923-162/13) in [this question on English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/70614/if-none-observe-me-why-not-if-none-observes-me):

> *7. November.* Unentrinnbare Verpflichtung zur Selbstbeobachtung: Werde ich von jemandem andern beobachtet, muß ich mich natürlich auch beobachten, werde ich von niemandem sonst beobachtet, muß ich mich um so genauer beobachten.

I’m intrigued by this alternative to the more common (I think):

> Wenn ich von jemandem andern beobachtet werde, muß ich …

I couldn’t find any information about this sentence type. How common is it? In what circumstances is it appropriate to use?

Feel free to answer in German.

Comment: I cannot say anything intelligent, but: You are right. You should separate your two questions. See https://de.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/anderer and follow the link for o to the inflections. (Some occurrences of the letter *e* are optional.)

Comment: Such an _uneingeleiteter Nebensatz_ is not at all uncommon. It’s also used in English: *Had I read that before, …* = *If I had read that before, …*.

Comment: *Had I read that before*... and *should you meet him*, (if you meet him) are common, but you don't say *have I read* for *if I have read*, or *am I observed by someone*..: for *if I am observed by someone*. If *be I observed by someone*... can be used at all in place of *if I am observed by someone* it will sound very old-fashioned. So it looks as though this type of sentece is more common in German than in English then?

Comment: It's certainly more common than in English, but is definitely even more so in the written language than the spoken one. Read any text in a video game item description and you'll see it (I happen to watch a lot of that sort of thing on YouTube in German). On Yu-Gi-Oh cards too, for example, it's used in sentences that describe what happens under certain other conditions. (Ist der blah hier, geschieht dann x y z). I do hear it spoken relatively often too. Then again, I can't give you anything erudite on this construction, just my own experience.

Comment: Found some related questions now: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/17355/verb-as-first-position-in-simple-sentences (English), https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/9533/verberstsatz-mit-doch (German), https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/20380/die-bedeutung-von-so-in-diesem-zusammenhang (German)

Comment: That was very interesting indeed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This type of clause is called *uneingeleiteter Nebensatz* (subordinate clause without a word to introduce it). It is marked by the finite verb being in first position, similar to a question, and of course the absence of any conjunction.

It is quite common in German and not at all limited to a particular register, being used in poetry, jurisprudence, newspapers and everyday language, as the examples below show. All types of conditional clauses can in principle appear in this form, it is a matter of style.

> Und bist du nicht willig, so brauch’ ich Gewalt. ([Goethe, c. 1782](https://de.wikisource.org/wiki/Erlk%C3%B6nig))
>   Von der Stirne heiß rinnen muß der Schweiß, soll das Werk den Meister loben. ([Schiller, 1799](https://de.wikisource.org/wiki/Das_Lied_von_der_Glocke_%281800%29))
>   Hat eine unbescholtene Verlobte ihrem Verlobten die Beiwohnung gestattet, so kann sie (…) auch wegen des Schadens, der nicht Vermögensschaden ist, eine billige Entschädigung in Geld verlangen. ([Bürgerliches Gesetzbuch, 1896, now repealed](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kranzgeld))
>   Haste was, biste was. (= *Hast du etwas, bist du etwas.*) (common saying)
>   Ist die Katze gesund, freut sich der Mensch. (advertising slogan, 1982)
>   Sind sie zu stark, bist du zu schwach. (advertising slogan, 1996)
>   Soll das Essen völlig vegan bleiben, ein Dressing aus Öl, Essig, Tomatenwürfeln und Frühlingszwiebeln rühren. ([recipe, 2001](http://www.chefkoch.de/rezepte/22661005721931/Schnelle-Falafel-in-Pitabrot.html))
>   Tritt er an, würde sich der Wettbewerb ändern. ([newspaper report, 2015](https://www.derwesten.de/politik/hillary-und-der-rote-bernie-aimp-id11180932.html))

(Note that in the second example, from Schiller’s *Lied von der Glocke*, the subordinate clause follows the main clause.)

Comment: Wie Du jetzt ausgerechnet aufs Kranzgeld gekommen bist...

Comment: Im letzten Beispiel passen „tritt“ und „würde ändern“ nicht zusammen. Das zeigt wohl, dass die Konstruktion nicht auf gutes Deutsch beschränkt ist ;)

Comment: @Carsten S: Ich suche Beispiele aus praktischen Gründen bevorzugt in Texten, die ich auswendig kann, und dazu gehören entweder besonders wichtige oder besonders interessante (unter sprachlichen oder, wie hier, historischen Aspekten). Wenn du lieber ein langweiliges juristisches Beispiel hättest, nimm doch [§ 919 Abs. 2 BGB](http://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/bgb/__919.html) (Abs. 1 ist der bekannte verrückt gewordene Grenzstein).

Comment: Ich wollte nur damit angeben, dass mir der Name geläufig ist. Was davon oder davon, dass Du den Text auswendig kannst, zu halten ist, müssen wir nicht erörtern.

Comment: @Carsten S: Der Text „Bürgerliches Gesetzbuch, 1896, now repealed“ ist übrigens ein Link zum Wikipedia-Artikel _Kranzgeld_. :-)