# What is this 'verb first' construction?

Tags: verb, word-order

I've listened to the song 'Oh Love' by Mark Forster for quite a while now and everytime I've heard it, this has always nibbled at me:

> **Geht**'s um nächste Schritte gehen,
>
> **Bin** ich wie ein altes Pferd,

I cannot understand why *bin* and *geht* are being placed first. Is it something that can be done stylistically in music/poetry/etc. or is this a valid construction in spoken German? The only thing I can assume is that perhaps a word is being missed out (e.g. *aber*?), but since this happens four times in the song I'm not certain at all and can't find anything about this anywhere.

Edit: I am fairly certain these are not question statements, just to clarify.

Comment: Also see http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/17355/verb-as-first-position-in-simple-sentences or (in German) http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/3012/kommt-ein-mann-in-eine-kneipe-wieso-haben-witze-diesen-besonderen-satzbau

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conditional clauses without conjunctions](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/26036/conditional-clauses-without-conjunctions)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a short form of the sentence

> **Wenn es** um*s* nächste Schritte gehen **geht**,
>
> (**dann**) bin ich wie ein altes Pferd.

*(Probably meaning, that he does not want to or is not able to take the next steps or many steps)*

Note that *dann* in the sentence can be omitted.

You can read about it [here](http://www.deutschegrammatik20.de/komplexer-satz/satzverbindung-konditional-wenn-falls-sofern-bei/) where it says

> Eine ungewöhnliche Variante eines Bedingungssatzes entsteht durch das Weglassen von wenn und dem Wechsel des Verbs in die Position 1 des Satzes. In der gesprochenen Sprache wird diese Variante selten benutzt.

Meaning a peculiar way to form a conditional clause is to omit *wenn* and switch the verb's position to the beginning of the sentence. Also, it says that this is not typical in spoken language.

---

So for the rest of the song this would mean

> Geht's um das was ich fühl Bin ich wie n' Wachsoldat
>
> **Wenn** es um das **geht**, was ich fühl, (**dann**) bin ich wie *n* Wachsoldat
>
> Geht's um das was ich denk Bin ich wie'n Pixelbild
>
> **Wenn** es umd das **geht**, was ich denk, (**dann**) bin ich wie *n* Pixelbild
>
> Geht's um das was wir haben Bin ich wie'n verwöhntes Kind
>
> **Wenn** es um das **geht**, was wir haben, (**dann**) bin ich wie *n* verwöhntes Kind

---

[Here](http://www.dartmouth.edu/%7Edeutsch/Grammatik/Subjunctive/KonjunktivII.html) is a link I found about the topic in English. It is briefly explained under the heading "Other forms of "if-then" clauses".

Comment: Ahhhhh right. I was aware in the past of being able to omit 'wenn' and put the verb first, but I didn't think that was what was happening here (since I was focusing so much on the 'bin' clause rather than the 'geht' clause).  Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: because you asked so nicely I shall ;)